# MATLAB gives error while generating MEX file from Fortran source codes

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, fortran, mex, lnk2019

When I try to generate the MEX file from the Fortran source code (TEINITG.F), Matlab always gives errors.After  downloading the trial versions of Intel Visual Fortran 11.1 Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1  linker, I used mex -setup to configure the environment. Then I tried to generate mex functions from FORTRAN Source Code (TEINITG.F).

However, when I type: `mex TEINITG.F`

Matlab shows link errors, like:

```
>>mex TEINITG.F
    Creating library C:\Users\xue\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_TDkmp3\templib.x and object 
C:\Users\xue\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_TDkmp3\templib.exp
 TEINITG.obj    : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TEINIT referenced in function 
_MEXFUNCTION
 TEINITG.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

 C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2010B~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'TEINITG.mexw32' failed.
```

I am running MATLAB R2010b-32bit on windows-64 bit. Might that be the source of problem?
I do not know how to deal with this error. Do you have any suggestions that may fix this problem?

Comment: Is there subroutine TEINIT in your code?

Comment: Could this be a name mingling issue with the Fortran compiler?